# XML import into SQL server nightmare

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xslt

I'm trying to import into SQL server a load of data from XML files and I'm having trouble adding the relevant keys (stored in the "keys" node) to link the XML data together in SQL server.

Please consider the XML snippet below.

```xml
<person>
    <keys>
        <key>xx8546</key>
        <key>yy369</key>
    </keys>

    <sex>f</sex>

   <names>
      <name>
         <prename>Sarah</prename>
         <surname>Connor</surname>
      </name>

      <name>
         <prename>Sarah</prename>
         <surname>Williams</surname>
      </name>
  </names>

  <mmx>
      <spouse-name>
          <prename>John</prename>
          <surname>Wyatt</surname>
      </spouse-name>
      <year-of-marriage>1985</year-of-marriage>
  </mmx>

  <pbx>
     <spouse-name>
        <prename>John</prename>
        <surname>Williams</surname>
     </spouse-name>

     <child-name>
        <prename>Sarah</prename>
        <surname>Bean</surname>
     </child-name>

     <year-of-baptism>2007</year-of-baptism>
 </pbx>
</person>
```

I need the relevant key to be added to each of the  nodes.

Here is part of my tsql:

```
DECLARE @x xml;
DECLARE @hdoc int;

SELECT @x = P
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\person.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Person(P)

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @x

--Person
SELECT * --into tbl_Person
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/persons/person/names/name', 2)
WITH (
[key]  nvarchar(100)  '../../keys/key', 
prename varchar(100),
surname varchar(100),
sex varchar(50) '../../sex'
)
```

The above code only inserts the first key value into both results eg `<key xx8546 </key>`. Please can you help me figure this out its really frustrating.

Thanks so much,

BN.

Comment: You could try inserting the persons and keys into two separate temporary tables first, and then inserting from the temporary tables (with an inner join) into your tbl_person table.

Comment: Thank you Tim. Please could you explain this further?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't import all the data at the same time since `<keys>` are not explicitly linked to other data.

You have to create a connections between your data: for example you can create tables holding your data adding an identity column, and then query the tables joining them on the identity column.

Here is a basic example of this approach:

```
create table tb_keys (id int identity(1,1), keycode nvarchar(50))
create table tb_names (id int identity(1,1), prename nvarchar(500), surname nvarchar(500))

declare @x xml;

select @x = p from openrowset (bulk 'c:\person.xml', single_blob) as person(p)

insert into tb_keys
select p.value('.', 'nvarchar(50)') as [key] from @x.nodes('/person/keys/key') AS T(p)

insert into tb_names
select 
    x.rec.query('./prename').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)') as 'prename',
    x.rec.query('./surname').value('.', 'nvarchar(500)') as 'surname'
from @x.nodes('/person//names/name') as x(rec)

select k.keycode, n.prename, n.surname 
from tb_keys k inner join tb_names n on k.id = n.id
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Andrea very helpful.  Please can you explain how to extract the value of the <sex> node? I'm having trouble getting at it (I'm new to xquery).  I would like to merge the name and sex data into the same table - please can you briefly explain how to go about this as I have loads of similar merges to do with this data :/ Thanks so much.

Comment: The XML also has further nodes that contain address details and other details in other nodes. How could this data be linked together? Could a similar method you mentioned above work?
<address town="Morpeth" county="Northhumberland" date="7.10.2013"/>

</address>

Comment: The idea to use the `IDENTITY` in order to *generate* a running number  reflecting the relative position and use this for a `JOIN` is creative and would work. But you should remove residuals like `@hdoc`, `xmlDoc` and `sp_xml_preparedocument` as this is not related to your solution...

Comment: Thank you @Shnugo, you are absolutely right: I started from the OP code and I forgot to remove the original tables. I fixed my answer removing unnecessary code.

Comment: @Andrea, great! One thing I'd think about is the type mismatch between the table's definition and the target type in `.value()` (+1 from my side)

Comment: @BabyNapoleon you can extract <sex> node with `select p.value('.', 'varchar(50)') as [key] from @x.nodes('/person/sex') AS T(p)`, but as pointed out by @Shnugo it is not clear how the sex information relates to other data

Answer (score 1):

`FROM OPENXML` with the corresponding SPs to prepare and to remove a document is outdated and should not be used any more. Rather use the appropriate [methods the XML data type provides](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx).

The element order is an inherent part of an XML document. It is not the best desing, but it is possible to link information via their *relative position*. Obviously you'd get into troubles if something is missing here.

I did not understand, how the `<sex>` is linked and what your `<mmx>` and `<pbx>` are doing here, but you can walk this road:

```
DECLARE  @xml XML=
N'<person>
    <keys>
        <key>xx8546</key>
        <key>yy369</key>
    </keys>
    <sex>f</sex>
    <names>
      <name>
         <prename>Sarah</prename>
         <surname>Connor</surname>
      </name>
      <name>
         <prename>Sarah</prename>
         <surname>Williams</surname>
      </name>
    </names>
  </person>';
```

The query starts with an *inline-tally*. The count of keys is returned as a derived table. In this case the `Tally` will return a *set* of `1` and `2`.

Now you can use this running number to grab the correlated data out out your XML:

```sql
WITH Tally(Nr) AS (SELECT TOP (@xml.value(N'count(/person/keys/key)','int')) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values) 
SELECT Nr
      ,@xml.value(N'(/person/keys/key[sql:column("Nr")]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS PersonKey
      ,@xml.value(N'(/person/names/name[sql:column("Nr")]/prename/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS PersonPrename
      ,@xml.value(N'(/person/names/name[sql:column("Nr")]/surname/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS PersonSurname

       -- this will return the <sex> for both (as there is just one...)
      ,@xml.value(N'(/person/sex/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS sex
FROM Tally;
```

The result

```
Nr  PersonKey   PersonPrename   PersonSurname   sex
1   xx8546      Sarah           Connor          f 
2   yy369       Sarah           Williams        f
```

Comment: Thanks Shnugo.  If there is only one name in the "name" element, the query returns nulls - how could I get around this?

Comment: @BabyNapoleon, if there is only one name, but you've got 2 keys, how should you link them? That's why I wrote *Obviously you'd get into troubles if something is missing here*. This is an erronous design... It might help to post another example of your XML (with one name) and the expected output.